# Objectify with Firestore native - no matching index found

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, sql-order-by, objectify, datastore

I have a collection of very simple Java objects which I store in Google Firestore database (native mode) using Objectify 6.0.7. Storing, deleting, and querying objects all work fine, but a query with an orderBy clause on a single field fails with "no matching index found". The exact same code works perfectly in a Datastore project (so the Java code is not in question).

I could not find clear documentation as to whether Objectify can work with Firestore and I suspect this is the issue. Thoughts?

This is the query:

```
ofy().load().type(Flight.class).order("-date").list();
```

and this is a sample record from that collection (French locale, but the date objects are valid):

```
airTime: "0.8666666666666667"
date: 20 décembre 2020 à 19:51:41 UTC-5
engineStartTime: 20 décembre 2020 à 19:51:41 UTC-5
engineStopTime: 20 décembre 2020 à 21:14:41 UTC-5
flightTime: 1.3833333333333333
from: "CYQB"
landingTime: 20 décembre 2020 à 21:08:41 UTC-5
takeOffTime: 20 décembre 2020 à 20:16:41 UTC-5
to: "CYVB"
```

Using an ascending order, e.g. `order("desc")` also fails, but removing the `.order('-desc')` function from the query altogether does not cause any error but of course returns results in random order.

I understand from the documentation that all single-field indexes should be created by default in Firestore and I see no way to create a single field index in the console. I therefore assume that an index exists for the `date` field used in the order function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectify v6 uses the com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore library as a low-level API. I'm pretty sure that library only works in Datastore Mode. Google has a completely different (and much more primitive) Java library for Firestore Mode.

So I think for now you need to use Datastore Mode and not Firestore Mode.

Comment: Right, but I was hoping to use Firebase auth using FlutterFire, which doesn't seem to support Datastore. So it seems like I will need to chosse between using Objectify and FlutterFire.

Comment: Bummer. Changing Objectify to work with the native Firestore API is not out of the question, but not likely to happen anytime soon. It's basically (another) ground up rewrite of Objectify. The API churn is rough.